# Is linear independence of equations equivalent to logical independence?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Suppose we have a system $S$ of homogeneous linear equations in $n$ variables, and an extra homogeneous equation $E$ in $n$ variables. If $E$ a linear combination of the equations in $S$, then it's a logical consequence of them, in particular it gives no further information in trying to work out the values of the variables. Is the converse true? That is, if $E$ is linearly independent of the equations of $S$, does $E$ automatically give extra information on the values of the variables?

More precisely, if $E$ is not a linear combination of the equations in $S$, does that imply that the solution space of $E$ *does not* contain the solution space of $S$ (so that the implication "any solution of $S$ is a solution of $E$" fails)?

Comment: The question is equivalent to this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2637044/row-space-of-a-matrix/2637323#2637323.  The answer follows from the rank-nullity theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true. To be more precise: If $V$ is a $n$-dimensional vector space over a field $F$, if $E$ is a vector space of linear of linear maps form $V$ into $F$ and if $\alpha$ is linear form from $V$ into $F$ which does not belong to $E$, then there's some element of $\ker\alpha$ which is does not belong to $\bigcap_{\beta\in E}\ker\beta$.

In order to prove it, let $\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_k$ be a basis if $E$. Then$$\bigcap_{\beta\in E}\ker\beta=\bigcap_{j=1}^k\ker\beta_j$$and therefore$$\dim\bigcap_{\beta\in E}\ker\beta=\dim\bigcap_{j=1}^k\ker\beta_j=n-k.$$If you add $\beta$ to the set $\{\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_k\}$, the dimension of the intersection of the kernels will be $n-k-1$, which is strictly smaller than $n-k$. Therefore, not all elements of $\ker\beta$ belong to $\bigcap_{j=1}^k\ker\beta_j$.

Comment: So basically we need the fact that the nullity of a non-zero linear form is always $n-1$, and the formula $\dim(U+V)=\dim(U)+\dim(V)-\dim(U\cap V)$?

Comment: @JackM That is relevant for this problem, yes.